# List data type error in listInsertLast?

Tags: c, list, abstract-data-type

I had a homework where I should implement a list data type in C, done everything but the tests that the tutors gave us, aren't passing correctly, here you go (I'll explain what wrong in a min):

```
#define ASSERT_TEST(b) do { \
    if (!(b)) { \
            printf("\nAssertion failed at %s:%d %s\n",__FILE__,__LINE__,#b); \
            return false; \
    } \
} while (0)
```

the tests failing are:
after I create a list with 4 elements in it using listInsertLast, and I use this:
`ASSERT_TEST(LIST_INVALID_CURRENT == listRemoveCurrent(list));`

and after I create another list with 4 elements using listInsertLast and I use this:
`ASSERT_TEST(listGetNext(list2) == NULL);`

NOTE: I use these lines immediately after creating the list to check if the inner iterator status haven't changed after listInsertLast function, the thing is they should work, and the value returned by these 2 lines should be correct ( LIST_INVALID_CURRENT  is enum value).. but they're not working, now I assume it's something that has to do with listInsertLast, they told us in the assignment we shouldn't change the inner iterator after adding at the end of the list, I tried everything possible, but still cant get them to work, my listInsertLast:

```
ListResult listInsertLast(List list, ListElement element) {
    if (!list || !element) {
        return LIST_NULL_ARGUMENT;
    }
    Node newElement = malloc(sizeof(*newElement));
    if (!newElement) {
        return LIST_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
    }
    newElement->data = list->copyElement(element);
    if (listGetSize(list) > 0) {
        Node save_iter = list->iter; // here? 
        list->iter = list->first;
        while (list->iter->next) {
            list->iter = list->iter->next;
        }
        list->iter->next = newElement;
        list->iter = list->iter->next;
        list->iter->next = NULL;
        list->iter = save_iter; // and here ?
    } else {
        list->first = newElement;
        list->first->next = NULL;
        list->iter = list->first; // or maybe here ?
    }
    list->size++;
    return LIST_SUCCESS;
}
```

What could the problem be, or if it has to do with other thing please help me..
Thank you very much <3

Comment: What is the `iter` field of your list struct for? I think that the iterating pointer should be just a local variable. Anyway, your error is here: `list->iter = list->iter->next;`: `list->iter->next`, which is `newElement->next`, isn't initialised and defererencing it in the next line leads to undefined behaviour.

Comment: (And when you check whether the list is empty, you should test `list->first == NULL`. Your check works, but if your list has many elements already, you will iterate all of them for each insertion, which may be wasteful. If you insert at the end often, it might be worthwile to keep a `last` pointer.)

Comment: This might be a good time to learn to use a debugger so you can trace into these functions and see if they are doing what you think they are.